# How to find the Width of the a view before the view is displayed?

Tags: android

How to find the Width of the a view before the view is displayed? I do not want to add a custom view and tap the dimensions in the OnChanged().

Comment: what you exactly want ?? describe more

Answer (score 50):

```java
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
View view = findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
view.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());

view.getMeasuredWidth(); // view width
view.getMeasuredHeight(); //view height
```

Comment: You might also keep in mind that if the view isn't inflated it's width and height will be 0.

Comment: You are right Joru. I used the ViewTreeObserver and resolved my issue. Thanks to all who tried to answer.

Comment: view.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight())  is deprecated

Comment: view.measure takes View.MeasureSpec as an arguments. [@Sandip Jadhav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9426895/7599300) is up to date.

Answer (score 40):

@dmytrodanylyk -- I think it will return width & height as 0 so you need to use following thing

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View contentview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURLAYOUTNAME, null, false);
contentview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = contentview.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = contentview.getMeasuredHeight();
```

It will give you right height & width.

Comment: That is what I need to determine if I should start a new row of checkboxes, first making it a single line and then prevent overflow by calculating the width...perfect thank you. coming from -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/24054428/1815624

Comment: Yes, this is a handy way to figure out the intrinsic size of a view based on its initial xml layout, and useful if say you're doing some dynamic calculations later on for layouts.

Answer (score 13):

You should use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` which is called for changes on the view, but before it is drawn.

```
costumView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

      costumView.getWidth();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
view.measure(size.x, size.y);
int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to use this technique as per [my answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21426049/383414):

Post a runnable from `onCreate()` that will be executed when the view has been created:

```
    contentView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    contentView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            contentHeight = contentView.getHeight();
        }
    });
```

This code will run on the main UI thread, after `onCreate()` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way...... WORK!!!

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {          
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if (fondo_iconos_height==0) { // to ensure that this does not happen more than once
      fondo_iconos.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
      fondo_iconos_height = fondo_iconos.getHeight();
      redraw_function();
  }

 }
```