# How can I force my checkbox's text to not wrap?

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button, android-checkbox

This is what my LinearLayout (horizontal) row looks like:

[image]

I want the text of the checkbox to be on one line; The buttons don't have to be that wide - they'll still have plenty of space with the checkbox text lengthened a bit. What in my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ckbxAllow_New_Items"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_Allow_New_Items" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOK"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_OK" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button_Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

...needs to change in order to force my checkbox text not to wrap?

### UPDATE

Following Der Golem's suggestion by adding this:

```
android:lines="1"
```

...and also changing layout_weight for the checkbox from 1 to 2 (set to 1 for the buttons) gave me what I wanted:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CheckBox inherits from CompoundButton, which inherits from Button, which inherits from **TextView**. So, it has all the properties, methods and attributes of these **ancestors**...
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

In particular, you are interested to the **TextView** properties, methods and attributes:
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

In particular, you're interested in the `android:lines` attribute, and set it to **1**.
This tells your CheckBox to be **exactly** 1 line tall.

You might also want to set the `android:ellipsize` attribute to some value (i.e.: 3 = end).
This tells your CheckBox to add three dots (ellipsis) to the end, start, center, ... of the truncated text.

**[EDIT]**

Being a decentant of TextView, it can use `setSingleLine` - Thanks to @CrandellWS for the comment.

Comment: Thanks; I had to also change weight for the checkbox from 1 to 2 (buttons' weight are set to 1). I show the satisfactory results in the Update.

Comment: Checkbox being a decentant of TextView With java can use `setSingleLine` see -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine()

Comment: @CrandellWS Thank you for the comment. I added that to my answer.

Comment: While still looking into this and found another option that may be desirable... `setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)` see-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean) relavance is better shown in article at -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)