# How to get the Height and Width of the View?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to get the height and width of the View before adding into layout or its is display. I have tried with using MeasuredHeight and MeasuredWidth of the view but its retursn as 0. Could you please help me out to resolve this?

Below code snippet I have tried out:

```
 int height = Column.MeasuredHeight;
 int width  = Column.MeasuredWidth;
```

Comment: Why you want it before setting layout?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9426895/5577679

Comment: @tompadre Thanks for the update. 

     Column.Measure(View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified), 
                View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified));

            int colHeight = Column.MeasuredHeight;

By using this solution, i am not getting actual height of the column.

Comment: then try the answer above. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16437972/5577679 Proper way to get dimensions before inflating view is by ViewTreeObserver which is explained in the answer above. Official documentation is here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Layout change event to not receive 0 as the height.
If you ask it too soon, the layout isn't drawn yet. Use the ViewTreeObserver of the layout that you want to measure.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout);
ViewTreeObserver vto = linearLayout.ViewTreeObserver;

vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, args) => {
    System.Console.WriteLine (linearLayout.Height);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But this event calls after which i set the column height. I need to to call this event before that.

Comment: @Parthiban Can't you just put the set column height into the vto.GlobalLayout?

Comment: i can able to set. But this Global Layout event trigger after my method called.

Comment: I meant like this:

    vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, args) => {
        //Set the height here.
    };

Answer (score 0):

Try view.getWidth() and view.getHeight()

Answer (score 0):

```
View view= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);
setContentView(view);
int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
int viewHeight = view.getHeight();
```